# How can I send automatic API request for some defined endpoints in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

I am using Postman to monitor our WordPress REST APIs daily. But now I want an automated process. I want to build a plugin that will at first send an auth request to an endpoint for logging in. Then, as a return, it will get an access token as a response. He can save the access token. Then, upon user prompt, it needs to send an API request to some defined endpoints (Will have some parameters in the header, and in the body as well for some endpoints). Then, it will show the status of all the API responses. Like for "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/testing: 200"
For "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/testing: 500 Internal error". like this. I will do the development and all the processes. Just need some guidance on how can I achieve that. Any suggestions on how can I get started will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use `wp_schedule_event()` function to call function automatic on specific time,

for more information visit https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/